# How to beat Challenge 1 of the 3rd Expansion in Duels of the Plainswalkers?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers

The title sums the question up pretty well.
I simply haven't been able to figure out how to beat this challenge with the limited mana given, the limited direct damage dealing possibilites and the many lifelink creatures in Sorin's battlefield.

What is the solution to this challenge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had problems with that challenge too.  Here's the solution on [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WvMgH32z5A).  I hope it helps.